# How to create sequentially updating selectize inputs in R shiny? i.e. choosing A from the 1st selection removes option A from any further selections

Tags: r, shiny

I have several selectize inputs, the number of which is dependent on a numeric input so it cannot be hard coded, I was wondering if it were possible to have each input affect any subsequent input. I.e. choosing A for the 1st and B from the 2nd will remove A and B from choices 3,4,.....

Here is my code to produce the inputs:

```
output$out <- renderUI({
    numinputs <- lapply(1:ncol(filteredData()), function(i){
      selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("fac", i), label = paste0("Select Factor ", i), choices = NULL, multiple = F)
    })
    shinyjs::hidden(numinputs)
  })

  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$go, 
    handlerExpr = {
    n <- seq(length.out = as.numeric(input$numfac))
    lapply(seq(ncol(filteredData())), function(i) {
      if(i %in% n) {
        shinyjs::show(id = paste0("fac", i))
      } else{
        shinyjs::hide(id = paste0("fac", i))
      }
    })
  })
```

And here is an example of me manually updating the 2nd selection input, note response is another selection that can be thought of as selection "0":

```
observeEvent(
    eventExpr = {
      input$csvFile
      input$numfac
      input$fac1
    },
    handlerExpr = {
      #print(input$fac1)
      facchoice2 <- setdiff(choice2(), c(input$response, input$fac1))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, 'fac2', choices = facchoice2, selected = NULL, server = TRUE)
      #

    }
  )
```

Is there a way for me to efficiently update all the remaining selectize inputs?

Overall it looks something like this as a reprex:

```
    library(shiny)


    ui <- fluidPage(
      fileInput("csvFile", "Upload your .csv file that you want to analyse"),
      selectizeInput("response", "Select", choices = NULL, multiple = F, options = list(maxItems = 1, placeholder = "placeholder", maxOptions = 30)),
      numericInput("numfac","Number of Factors you want in your model:", value = 1, min = 0),
      uiOutput(outputId = "out"),
      fluidRow(
        actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Click me!"),
        actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Update Choices!"))
    )


    server <- function(input, output) {
      filteredData <- reactive({
        data <- as.data.frame(read.csv(input$csvFile$datapath, stringsAsFactors = F))
        data <- remove.na(data)$x
        as.data.frame(data)
      })

choice2 <- reactive({
    colnames(filteredData())
  })

      output$out <- renderUI({
        numinputs <- lapply(1:ncol(filteredData()), function(i){
          selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("fac", i), label = paste0("Select Factor ", i), choices = NULL, multiple = F)
        })
        shinyjs::hidden(numinputs)
      })

      observeEvent(
        eventExpr = input$go, 
        handlerExpr = {
          n <- seq(length.out = as.numeric(input$numfac))
          lapply(seq(ncol(filteredData())), function(i) {
            if(i %in% n) {
              shinyjs::show(id = paste0("fac", i))
            } else{
              shinyjs::hide(id = paste0("fac", i))
            }
          })
        })

    observeEvent(
      eventExpr = input$csvFile,
      handlerExpr = {
       updateNumericInput(session,"numfac","Number of Factors you want in your model:", value = 1, min = 0, max = ncol(filteredData),step=1)
       }
      )

      observeEvent(
        eventExpr = {
          input$response
          input$csvFile
        },
        handlerExpr = {
          facchoice1 <- setdiff(choice2(), input$response)
          updateSelectizeInput(session, 'fac1', choices = facchoice1, selected = NULL, server = TRUE)
        }
      )

      observeEvent(
        eventExpr = {
          input$csvFile
          input$numfac
          input$fac1
        },
        handlerExpr = {
          facchoice2 <- setdiff(choice2(), c(input$response, input$fac1))
          updateSelectizeInput(session, 'fac2', choices = facchoice2, selected = NULL, server = TRUE)

        }
      )
    }

    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```